# CarrierWave + Cloudinary : chain transformation / crop & scale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, cloudinary

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make chain transformation.

Given an image I want to apply it a 'pad crop' ([example](http://a1.res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/b_rgb:dddddd,c_pad,h_80,w_80/face_top.jpg) / [doc](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#reference)) so something like:

`cloudinary_transformation transformation: [{  width: 450, height: 450, crop: :pad }]`

Then, the user will [crop the padded image with JCrop or whatever](http://origin1tech.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/ss-e1342883129910.jpg), so I will store `crop_x`, `crop_y`and `crop_width` and then, I want to have multiple size of this cropped image, like a `200x200` `:thumb`.

What I have:

```
# Image version used for cropping
version :large do
  cloudinary_transformation transformation: [{  width: 450, height: 450, crop: :pad }]
end

# A 200x200 version of the cropped image
version :thumb do
  cloudinary_transformation transformation: [{  width: 200, height: 200, crop: :pad }]
  process :crop_thumb
end

def crop_thumb
  return { x:      model.crop_x,
           y:      model.crop_y,
           width:  model.crop_width,
           height: model.crop_width,
           crop:   :pad }
end
```

But the width of the result image is `crop_width` and not 200, of course...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I finally did it:

```
version :thumb do
  process :crop_thumb
end

def crop_thumb
  transformations = []
  transformations << { x: model.crop_x, y: model.crop_y, width: model.crop_width, height: model.crop_width, crop: :crop }
  transformations << { width: 200, height: 200, crop: :fill }
  { transformation: transformations }
end
```